# Java - Reading input from a file. java.io.FilterInputStream.available(Unknown Source)?

Tags: java, file-io

I haven't written any Java in years and I went back to refresh my memory with a simple 'read-from-file' example.  Here is my code..

```
import java.io.*;
public class filereading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\file.txt");
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        BufferedInputStream bs = null;
        DataInputStream ds = null;

        try
        {
            fs = new FileInputStream(file);
            bs = new BufferedInputStream(bs);
            ds = new DataInputStream(ds);

            while(ds.available()!= 0)
            {
                String readLine = ds.readLine();
                System.out.println(readLine);
            }

            ds.close();
            bs.close();
            fs.close();
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles fine (although apparently ds.readLine() is deprected), but at runtime, this gives me

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.available(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   filereading.main(filereading.java:21)

What gives?

Comment: Also please note that `.available()` probably doesn't know what you think it does.

Comment: Not in the question, but you should close the resource (`FileInputStream`) in a finally block. To aid this pull assignment out of the `try` block (and make the variable `final`).

Comment: @Tom Hawtin. +1. And only do this once on the most-derived resource handle, in this case `DataInputStream ds`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made a simple typo:

```
ds = new DataInputStream(ds);
```

should be

```
ds = new DataInputStream(bs);
```

Your code is initializing the `DataInputStream` with a null source, since `ds` hasn't been created yet.

Having said that, Jon Skeet's answer gives a better way to write a file-reading program (and you should always use `Readers`/`Writers` rather than `Streams` when dealing with text).

Comment: Solution: Use much better variable names!

Comment: The line above that is incorrect too - it should be BufferedInputStream(fs) rather than BufferedInputStream(bs)

Comment: Heh, I didn't even notice that one. Better variable names would definitely help here.

Comment: I've gotta stop writing code so early in the morning.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To read a text file, use `BufferedReader` - in this case, wrapped round an `InputStreamReader`, wrapped round a `FileInputStream`. (This allows you to set the encoding explicitly - which you should definitely do.) You should also close resources in finally blocks, of course.

You should then read lines until `readLine()` returns null, rather than relying on `available()` IMO. I suspect you'll find that `readLine()` was returning `null` for the last line in the file, even though `available()` returned 2 to indicate the final `\r\n`. Just a hunch though.

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```